Android Devices Log Collector
I've been searching for a few days on the market for a tool, whether paid or free, I need something like a log collector for Android devices. Imagine my log is on the devices and I want something that collects them and sends them somewhere centralized. The problem is that I looked at, their offer to integrate the SDK into the app and they used a lot of internet since I'm limited I need something that sends log data once a day. For now, I found that fluentbit.If you have any suggestions many thanks. I don't know Telegraf, Prometheus logstash is it possible to run them on Android?
Thank you!
